# How do I do the same thing as with

Tags: sql, node.js, database, express

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

---

```
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            return res.render("register");
        }
```

How can I do the same thing but using mySql? Im pretty much new to SQl and converting my work to mySql from mongodb is way harder then i thought even tho SQL syntax is pretty easy. I wanna learn SQL database cuz it seems to be more in demand rn. Can u guys help me out on this one? I just wanna do simple user object and then have a ability to authenticate it using passport library.
Thanks in advance